# unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int' while reading file

Tags: python, django, pytest

I am writing unit test cases. I create a file objects and reading it, but I am getting the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'

Method:

```
def uploadExamineeDetails(request, exam_id):
    try:
        upload_file = request.FILES['upload-file']
    except Exception:
        return [_('Uploaded file is required.')]
    try:
        exam = get_object_or_404_from_admin(CourseExam, request, exam_id)
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=upload_file.read())
        # further code
```

My testing code:

```
def test_uploadExamineeDetails(self):

    self.examinee_result = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR),\
                                        'var/sample_files_for_testing/examinees_result_upload.xls')
    file = File(open(self.file, errors='ignore'))
    uploaded_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file=file, field_name='upload-file', name='examinee_result.xls',
                                        content_type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel', size = file.size, charset = None)
    self.request.FILES['upload-file'] = uploaded_file
    xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=uploaded_file.read())
    response = uploadExamineeDetails(self.request, 1)
    assert isinstance(response, tuple), 'should upload the examinee details'
```

data in excel file:

```
[{'Enrollment Number': '', 'Username': 'exam_course_manager',
 'row_num': 1, 'Obtained Score': 60.0, 'GR Number': ''},
 {'Enrollment Number': '', 'Username': 'instructor',
 'row_num': 2, 'Obtained Score': 20.0, 'GR Number': ''}]
```

Traceback:

```
       (py_3.5_dj_1.9) dikshaj@PTU16SPSD79:~/Projects/DROANA_3.0/droana/droana$ py.test  droana/apps/course_planner/tests/test_methods.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
Django settings: droana.test_settings (from command line option)
rootdir: /home/dikshaj/Projects/DROANA_3.0/droana/droana, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.1.2, cov-2.4.0, ipdb-0.1.dev2
collected 1 items 

droana/apps/course_planner/tests/test_methods.py F

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.5.2-final-0 -----------
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov


=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________ TestMethods.test_uploadExamineeDetails ____________________

self = <droana.apps.course_planner.tests.test_methods.TestMethods testMethod=test_uploadExamineeDetails>

    def test_uploadExamineeDetails(self):
        """
            Test uploadExamineeDetails method
            """
        self.examinee_result = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR),\
                                            'var/sample_files_for_testing/examinees_result_upload.xls')
        file = File(open(self.file, errors='ignore'))
        uploaded_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file=file, field_name='upload-file', name='examinee_result.xls',
                                            content_type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel', size = file.size, charset = None)
        self.request.FILES['upload-file'] = uploaded_file
>       xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=uploaded_file.read())

droana/apps/course_planner/tests/test_methods.py:100: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/opt/myvirtual/py_3.5_dj_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py:435: in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
/opt/myvirtual/py_3.5_dj_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/book.py:91: in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
/opt/myvirtual/py_3.5_dj_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/book.py:1226: in getbof
    opcode = self.get2bytes()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <xlrd.book.Book object at 0x7fb57b458c88>

    def get2bytes(self):
        pos = self._position
        buff_two = self.mem[pos:pos+2]
        lenbuff = len(buff_two)
        self._position += lenbuff
        if lenbuff < 2:
            return MY_EOF
        lo, hi = buff_two
>       return (BYTES_ORD(hi) << 8) | BYTES_ORD(lo)
E       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'

/opt/myvirtual/py_3.5_dj_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/book.py:631: TypeError
```

The code throwing an exception while reading this line:

```
xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=upload_file.read())
```

This is what I have done. I create a file, stored it in directory, then open it and made an in memory object, as shown in code. According to error I get it that this error occur when you try to compare a string to int. but I am not getting why this occurring in reading file, and where.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace you're seeing in your question? For what it's worth, the error message you've shown involves the bit shift operator (<<), which I'm not seeing in any of your code, so I'm guessing some of the library code you're using is throwing the error. The stack trace will help narrow down what parameters could be causing the problem.

Comment: I have added traceback, Even if I upload a txt file still getting the same issue. I think issue is occurring while reading the file. I will be very thankful if anyone can give me the solution of this problem.

Comment: It does look like a problem with xlrd, but I can't find a solution online and I'm not familiar with that library. If you change the line `xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=upload_file.read())` to `xlrd.open_workbook(filename='name-of-file-on-disk.xls')`, where you've saved off the file content to an actual file, does the problem persist?

Comment: With the filename I can open the file, but that same code is working while I am uploading the file via User interface. Is there any any encoding problem in my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode:

```
file = File(open(self.file, 'rb'))
```

By default, files are opened with mode `'r'`, which reads in the file as a stream of Unicode characters (type `str` on Python 3). That get2bytes method in xlrd expects a stream of bytes, which is returned when opening the file in `'rb'` mode.

This requirement seems to be misdocumented by xlrd, which says any ["string or an mmap.mmap object or some other behave-alike object"](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook) will do for `file_contents`. Peering into the code, `BYTES_ORD` is [defined as the identity function on Python 3](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/fcfdb721abe650c0b25d8a874dc7314e9eb8dc59/xlrd/timemachine.py#L19), so when `file_contents` is passed into `get2bytes`, a `str` blob will result in `'c'[0] << 8`, which fails, but a `bytes` blob will result in `b'c'[0] << 8`, which succeeds (because each element in a `bytes` blob is an `int`).